# How can I extract images from PDF when I have their positions?

Tags: python, pdf

I am trying to get some images from PDF, and I have the specific positions of them. How can I do this?  If possible, capturing screenshots is fine, too.

I have got the specific positions of those images through pdfminer. But I don't know what to do next, there is sparse document about pdfminer.

Comment: Have you checked this link: https://denis.papathanasiou.org/archive/2010.08.04.post.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I have read the doc, but I just want images that contain text and pic. I got the positions of start title and end title of the pics,  I want to capture the content between these positions as images. @iAmTryingOK